# How to pick distinct rows?

Tags: python, r

my Data looks like this

```
SeqName                    GO_ID
TRINITY_DN1348_c0_g1_i1  C:GO:0005777
TRINITY_DN1336_c0_g1_i1  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021 
TRINITY_DN1859_c0_g2_i1  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021 
TRINITY_DN463_c0_g1_i2   C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021 
TRINITY_DN451_c0_g1_i1   C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021
TRINITY_DN1437_c0_g1_i2  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021
TRINITY_DN2441_c0_g1_i1  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021
TRINITY_DN2441_c0_g1_i2  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021
TRINITY_DN2441_c0_g1_i3  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021
```

i want to pick the any one or first sequence name whose GO_ID value is same and whose SeqName differs at i level ? (i mean i1, i2, i3)

Output should be like

```
SeqName                    GO_ID
TRINITY_DN1348_c0_g1  C:GO:0005777
TRINITY_DN1336_c0_g1  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021    
TRINITY_DN1859_c0_g2  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021    
TRINITY_DN463_c0_g1   C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021    
TRINITY_DN451_c0_g1   C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021
TRINITY_DN1437_c0_g1  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021
TRINITY_DN2441_c0_g1  C:GO:0005783; C:GO:0016021
```

Comment: Look at `unique()`.

Comment: In R, you can do `df[!duplicated(df$GO_ID), ]` where `df` is your dataframe.

Comment: Can you please (i) create a reproducible example, and (ii) decide whether you want an `R` solution or a `Python` solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `pandas` library of python, and load your dataset as a dataframe.

```
df.drop_duplicates(['GO_ID'], keep='first')
```

> keep='first' : Drop duplicates except for the first occurrence.